# Uncaught ReferenceError: Promise is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, promise, google-chrome-app

A Chrome App I've made works perfectly fine for me, but another user gets an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Promise is not defined` when starting it up. For some reason it doesn't understand what a Promise is. The code works perfectly fine on my end and I've never gotten that error before, but the user gets it every time. What could be the issue here?

Comment: The problem is that there isn't such a variable in my code, and even when I'm using the same version the user is using on my PC, everything loads fine. I don't know if posting the code will help, because it is "Uglified" and pretty hard to read. Could the problem be because of an outdated browser or something? I've even looked through the code and the word Promise is mentioned only 2 times and both times it is properly used with the "new" keyword, like this: new Promise(function(a){})

Comment: There must be something in your code trying to use `Promise` (since it says `ReferenceError`). Or if you included scripts from other domain the problem might be in those scripts.

Comment: It might be because of outdated browser since `Promise` is [only supported after Chrome 32](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: That must be it! The user updated his browser and everything works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user updated Chrome to the latest version and that apparently fixed it. I don't know how, since his version was from December 2013 and surely Promises worked back then. I don't know. It definitely isn't a problem with the code since I'm running the same exact version the user is running and I've never encountered that error.

But yeah - apparently fixed.

EDIT: Apparently Promises only work since Chrome 32, so yeah that's why the error.

Comment: I would not use native promises (yet) if I were you, you're much safer using a library like Bluebird.

Comment: What do you mean? Why not?

Comment: They're unstable and only provide a fragment of the functionality libraries do. They exist to interoperate with user code cleanly, not to replace libraries.

Answer (score 2):

To support IE and older versions of other browsers, you should consider loading a polyfill for the Promise object.

One implementation you can use out of the box with a `<script>` tag is available [here](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill/blob/master/Promise.js).

Answer (score 0):

### Primise in Old Browsers

**​Android 4.x browser Promise**
​

I had similar problem ​in Android 4.X browsers. I solved it by using es6-promise in webpack config:
​
​Promise: 'es6-promise'
​

```
​plugins: [
    ​    //tells webpack where to store data about your bundles.
    ​    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),        ​
    ​    //makes jQuery available in every module
    ​    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    ​        $: 'jquery',        ​
    ​        jQuery: 'jquery',
    ​        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    ​        Promise: 'es6-promise'
    ​    }),
​    // Configure path for served CSS files ("desktop_css" will be served as /dist/desktop_css.css)    ​
​    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),    ​
​],
```

---

Can I use Promise: ​http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises

---

some related links:

​​[axios IE promise doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769777/axios-ie-promise-doesnt-work/48203092)

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/188

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4254

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in this field, but maybe this will help someone.

Got the same issue on Cordova Android app on Android 4.4.

Fixed by running this commands

```
 1. cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-inapppurchase --save
 2. cordova plugin add https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase#1968e41d173481eb2e6a536fdc55cc9e9253e6d5 --save
```