# axios IE promise doesn't work

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I am using axios for ajax communication.
I have problem with IE. IE return error about Promise.
IE doesn't know anything about Promise.

I am writing react/redux but I tried axios in plain JS and same result

Could someone help me with it?
I am confused because axios should work on IE 8+
I tried on IE 11 (windows 10 64bit)

My trial is written as is in example on axios homepage

thx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to include a promise polyfill if the browser has no promise implementation. This sounds complicated but there are really good libs.

The axios docs mention it:
axios depends on a native ES6 Promise implementation to be supported. If your environment doesn't support ES6 Promises, you can polyfill.

If you use just JS without transpiling or bundling you can try [es6-promise](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise)

or if you use babel you can take [its polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/)

Comment: Works for me as well when using ```babel-polyfill```.

Answer (score 2):

**Android 4.x and axios And Promise**

In Android 4.X I had similar problem. I solve it by using es6-promise in webpack config:

*Promise: 'es6-promise'*

```
plugins: [
    //tells webpack where to store data about your bundles.
    new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}),

    //makes jQuery available in every module
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Promise: 'es6-promise'
    }),

    // Configure path for served CSS files ("desktop_css" will be served as /dist/desktop_css.css)
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
],
```

For more Information look at:

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/188

> Yes Promise wasn't introduced for Android until 4.4.4

http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises

---

'Promise' is undefined

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4254

Comment: Promises are not supported on 4.4: http://caniuse.com/#search=promise
you have to implement a polifill for this.
Have a look at https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise or similar.

https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase/issues/9#issuecomment-203414481