# Error Promise is not defined when I start my unit test on async action Redux

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, redux

I'am developping a web app with REACT + REDUX in javascript everything is working ^^

but I'am trying to make unit test on async action with mocha and I'am stuck with an error

```
 1) async actions creates login async action:
 ReferenceError: Promise is not defined
  at Axios.request (node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js:62:17)
  at Axios.(anonymous function) [as post] (node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js:113:17)
  at Function.wrap (node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/bind.js:9:15)
  at index.js:27:11
  at Object.dispatch (node_modules/redux-thunk/lib/index.js:12:16)
  at Context.<anonymous> (test.js:28:11)
```

this is my test.js

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as actions from '../../src/actions/index';
import * as types from '../../src/constants/constants_session';
import nock from 'nock';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import axios from 'axios';
import expect from 'expect'; // You can use any testing library

const middlewares = [ thunk, ReduxPromise ]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)

describe('async actions', () => {
afterEach(() => {
 nock.cleanAll()
})

it('creates login async action', (done) => {
 nock('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
   .get('/auth')
   .reply(200)

const expectedActions = [
  { type: types.LOGGED_SUCCESSFULLY }
]
const store = mockStore()

store.dispatch(actions.login())
  .then(() => { // return of async actions
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
  })
  .then(done) // test passed
  .catch(done) // test failed
  })
})
```

and this is my action.js

```
export function login(accountDetails) {
const url = `${ROOT_URL}/auth/`;
return function(dispatch) {
  axios.post(url, accountDetails)
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        dispatch(loginSuccess(response.data.response.data.user));
        browserHistory.push("/admin");
      }
      else
        dispatch(loginError(response.data.response.message));
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
      dispatch(loginError(response.data.response.message));
    });
  }
}
```

I hope you can help me
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing `Promise` in your test environment, which Axios is using and which is part of ES6.

Using a polyfill should work, as described in [Axios upgrade guide](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md#es6-promise-polyfill).

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
var axios = require('axios');
```

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you're using **babel**, you could use [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/).

`$ npm install --save babel-polyfill`

`import "babel-polyfill";`

I have also tried `es6-promise` first, unfortunately with no luck.

But I found this short, clear, complete and right to the subject answer: [axios IE promise doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769777/axios-ie-promise-doesnt-work)