# Axios call is failing in IE

Tags: reactjs, axios

The Axios call in my react app is failing in IE browser, getting error in the console like - Promise is undefined and the call is not happening, due to this the app is not at all working in IE browser. Can anyone let me know what is the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [axios IE promise doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769777/axios-ie-promise-doesnt-work)

Comment: @Nitsew Thank you for the link. Im using react with gulp so Im not sure how to include this in my app. Can you please help here?